# How to get past vertical sewage pipes?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

After getting inside the sewer of South Park, I used alien probe to cross the gap. And then climbed down the stairs. Now I can see a water flowing down. There is a valve above it. How do i reach it?

Comment: you know, as Lyrion's answer is obviously correct, it'd be nice to accept it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get through the sewer flow, you'll see the valve above it twinkeling a little. When they do that you can shoot at it.

**Shoot at the valve.**

*Edit: As Eric Tobias said there are 2 kinds of valves, the ones on top of the pipes which you can shoot, and the yellow ones next to the pipes which you can use by activating them.*

Comment: It may be noteworthy that there are two types of these sewage pipes. The first can be shut by the valve as discussed above, the second features a valve on the other side of the stream, you will get to those later on when you approach the stream from the other direction.